# Unable to hit POST in C# WebApi

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

I've been all over the stackoverflows and can't seem to fix this issue I am having.

I am trying to write an error reporting service for a little app that I wrote that hits my internal api with the exception thrown and emails it to me.

As my code is, I can't seem to even hit the API controller.  My request returns a 500 error and the breakpoint I have set at the controller is never hit.

Here is the api controller (ErrorController.cs):

```
    [HttpPost]
    // POST: api/Error
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Exception err)
    {
        var result = _service.SendEmail(err);

        return Request.CreateResponse(result, err);
    }
```

And its config in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ErrorApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/error",
            defaults: new { controller = "error" }
        );
```

And where I am attempting to call it, in a service, in a catch block:

```
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:61857/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/error",   err).Result;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Is there anything obvious I am missing?  I am a little unsure of how to correctly send an exception as a JSON object and then pass it into my email service. I think that might be where I am screwing it up.

Thank you in advance for any help! :)

Comment: Your method is called Post, not Error.  You're route thinks it should be Error. Get your names to agree and you should be fine.

Comment: I specify the controller in webapiconfig.  My other controllers are configured and called the same way, and I access their get methods with this kind of route: "api/{controller}/{id}." You don't actually put the method name in the route in webapi

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is a very certain answer for this question in this website previously posted, but just because I'm trying to help I give you my opinion. I think you should use the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse to get a granular control of your client:
something like old school:

```
                string uri = // whatever is your uri (http://url);
                string Method = // whichever is your method ("POST")
                HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
                req.KeepAlive = false;
                req.Method = Method.ToUpper();

                if (("POST,PUT").Split(',').Contains(Method.ToUpper()))
                {
                    content = // here write your content Stream.ReadToEnd() or something similar

                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
                    req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
                    req.ContentType = // write your content type "text/xml";
                    Stream PostData = req.GetRequestStream();
                    PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    PostData.Close();
                }

                HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

                Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
                StreamReader loResponseStream =
                new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), enc);

                string Response = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

                loResponseStream.Close();
```

that way you can see what you are actually doing. Then let your wevservice takes care of whatever you send to it.

or use some other package or assembly which is really tested.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this way still returned a 500 error.

Also hola paisano! :D de cuba?

Comment: Well paisano, a 500 error is a completely different issue because it is most of the time related with an access permission to a resource in your web server. So something should be wrong with your iis or your application is breaking or causing unexpected behavior in the server side. So try to send a common get or post call instead an error like dbugger said